# Trying to Print every prime number in a Calendar with p

Tags: c, arrays, testing, calendar

Im having an issue with my code im trying to do for class. I have to make every prime number in a one month calendar printed out with "p", instead of the number for that day in the month. THe code i have here only prints out the first 3 days of the month with p, which is incorrect, and the rest of the days are the regular numbers. Can someone help please?:

```
int i, ndays, start, prime=1, p, day=0, array[32];

printf("Enter number of days in month: ");
scanf("%d", &ndays);
printf("Enter starting day of the week (1=Sun, 7=Sat): ");
scanf("%d", &start);

for(i=0; i<start-1; i++)
         printf("%3c", ' ');
for(i=1;i<=ndays; i++){
                  day++;
                  array[i-1] = day;
                  for(p=2; p<day; p++){
                           if(day%p == 0)
                                      prime = 0;
                                      }
                  if(prime == 1)
                           printf("%3c", 'p');
                  else
                      printf("%3d", day);
                  if((i+start-1)%7 == 0)
                                   printf("\n");
                  }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `prime` variable is initialized to 1, set to 0 if a prime is found, but never reset again to 1.

Comment: so if i added an else making prime 1 again, after the if statement setting prime to 0, should work?

Comment: Although it doesn't answer your question, you might want to look at the Sieve of Eratosthenes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: you can set `prime = 1` at the top of your `for` loop (where you're incrementing `day`). you wouldn't have to initialize `prime` at the very top, as you'd set it before using it each loop.

Comment: also, `int day` appears redundant, as it will be the same value as `i`.

Comment: while taking the square root of `day` may be out of the scope of this assignment, at least think about how many numbers can be divided evenly by more than half their value.

Comment: @polarysekt that worked! thank you so much! you saved me hours of troubleshooting! But one question, would it be correct if 1 are printed out as p? I would think 1 wouldn't be prime. and the days variable wasn't there originally, that was just left there from me trying multiple things to try to get this code to work haha.

Comment: The only bug left would be the special case if `day == 1`. You can implement it A.) within the loop -- either at the top, when you set `prime = 1`, or when you check for prime, via, `if(prime==1 && day!=1)` or B.) implement the  special case display for 1 before the loop, then start your loop at `2`, of course, updating initial conditions for (redundant) `day` as well by initializing it to 1 instead of 0 in the top line. [I was still typing this when you responded].

Comment: To save some time when debugging, I commented out the two prompts, and set `ndays` and `start` to some arbitrary values to avoid inputting the values. (I was experimenting with `echo -e "30\n3\n" | ./a.out` but it skewed the output [no newlines after inputs] so as possibly to be confusing.)

Comment: thanks i got it to work, just inmplemented an extra if statement at the printing section of the numbers and then made the original if and else statements to else if's that worked for me.

Comment: By the way, check out what happens if user enters invalid inputs (esp. if ndays > 31 or start > 7 or < 1). Anyways, since you've gotten your solution, I went ahead and made a couple of changes [here](https://gist.github.com/polarysekt/b50453965022723872a3) if you're interested. I added input validation (with feedback), a days header, made some small adjustments to initial conditions, removed unused variables, made `p` a char, simplified `if(prime==1)`, consolidated a few lines, printed a final newline, adjusted to avoid double newline on fringe cases, and drowned it in comments.

Comment: Not to be a bother, but i need to know multiple variations of this code for my test in order to get an A, so how would i go about identifying the number of weeks and say for example: print out a calendar that skips the second week of the month